# How do I make a static class thread-safe?

Tags: c#, wpf, logging, thread-safety, static-methods

I have a simple simple logging class that is static. However, it's definitely not thread safe as every call attempts to write to the same file. I get these exceptions:

```
The process cannot access the file 'logfile.txt' because it is being used by another process.
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) 
...
```

What is the best way to make it thread safe?

```
public static class Logger
{
    private static readonly string LOG_FILENAME = "logfile.txt";
    private static readonly string LOG_FOLDER = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "App name");
    private static readonly string LOG_FULLPATH = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "App name", LOG_FILENAME);

    public static void LogMessageToFile(string msg)
    {
        msg = string.Format("{0:G}: {1}{2}", DateTime.Now, msg, Environment.NewLine);
        File.AppendAllText(LOG_FULLPATH, msg);
    }
}
```

As a logging function, I would like to be able to access it from many different parts of my code (hence, why I chose it to be static). However, I'm imagining that to make it thread safe, I'll always have to pass it a common object to lock() on, which I think defeats the purpose of a static function. Or is that not the case?

Comment: Why not make it a singleton instead?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
public static class Logger
{
    private static readonly string LOG_FILENAME = "logfile.txt";
    private static readonly string LOG_FOLDER = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "App name");
    private static readonly string LOG_FULLPATH = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "App name", LOG_FILENAME);

    private static Object theLock=new Object();

    public static void LogMessageToFile(string msg)
    {
        msg = string.Format("{0:G}: {1}{2}", DateTime.Now, msg, Environment.NewLine);
        lock (theLock)
        {
            File.AppendAllText(LOG_FULLPATH, msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `lock ensures that one thread does not enter a critical section of code while another thread is in the critical section. If another thread attempts to enter a locked code, it will wait, block, until the object is released.`

Comment: Is this solution preferable to making a non-static class that accepts an object (with perhaps a constructor that accepts a single string: the message to be logged), and locking that?

Comment: +1. @raney - locking what? You need `lock` around writing to file (must be at most one object to lock on per file, having one static lock for all files is acceptable for sample code). Note that for real logging it would be better to use existing solutions.

Comment: Do not lock on writeable fields. 
Therefore *theLock* should be a readonly field.
see [Blocks should be synchronized on read-only fields][1] 


  [1]: https://rules.sonarsource.com/csharp/RSPEC-2445

Comment: @Syntony Since the field is assigned once and only once during thel lifetime of the object  sthat locks on it, none of the conditions apply.

Answer (score 2):

In your LogMessageToFile method, you need a lock to prevent multi-thread accessing:

```
private static Object _mylock = new Object();
public static void LogMessageToFile(string msg)
{
    lock(_mylock)
    {
       msg = string.Format("{0:G}: {1}{2}", DateTime.Now, msg, Environment.NewLine);
       File.AppendAllText(LOG_FULLPATH, msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: - 1 _myloc must be static to be accessible in a static method!